# Using Crypto Gpgme to check signatures

Tags: haskell, gnupg

I'm trying to use Crypto.Gpgme to check pgp signatures.
I have a couple of functions :

```
parseData signedData = do
  res <- liftIO $ verifyPlain' "gpghome" (DBL.toStrict signedData) ""
  case res of
    Left err -> return $ Left $ errorString err
    Right ((err, _, fg):xs, msg) -> case errorString err of
      "Success" -> return $ Right (fg, msg)
      _         -> return $ Left $ errorString err

parseRequest d = do
  parsed <- parseData d
  case parsed of
    Left err        -> throw $ UnknownError err
    Right (fg, msg) -> return (fg, msg)
```

That way from Web.Scotty I can just use `(fg, msg) <- parseRequest =<< body` to get the fingerprint of the signing key, and the signed message (I use the fingerprint for auth, and the message is the actual request).

That code does not work, it segfaults.
I've found something that does work :

```
parseData signedData ctx = do
  res <- verifyPlain ctx (DBL.toStrict signedData) ""
  case res of
    Left err -> return $ Left $ errorString err
    Right ((err, _, fg):xs, msg) -> case errorString err of
      "Success" -> return $ Right (fg, msg)
      _         -> return $ Left $ errorString err

parseRequest d = do
  parsed <- liftIO $ withCtx "gpghome" "C" OpenPGP $ parseData d
  case parsed of
    Left err        -> throw $ UnknownError err
    Right (fg, msg) -> return (fg, msg)
```

So that's fine, I guess errorString accesses the Ctx for some reason, whatever.
Now to my actual real problem, that code works only once. If I try to check the same query twice, the first one works fine, the second one gives UnknownError "No public key", so it looks like parseRequest gets a Left for no good reason.

I'm guessing there's a bug in the library, and it must not free something correctly between requests or something. I tried allocating a ctx in my main, and using that one ctx everywhere, but same error.
Any idea of what I'm doing wrong, if it's me, or how to fix that or work around it if it's the library ?

Thanks

Comment: If the package exposes an API with which you can cause a segfault then I'd call that a bug and file an issue (separately, in addition to the other bug you discuss).

Comment: I opened an issue on github, hoping this is still active

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out the problem, I had a setCurrentDirectory somewhere else in my code and the path got invalid. I'm guessing the Ctx must store the path to the gpghome, and using SetCurrentDirectory basically makes the Ctx invalid.

There is still a bug with verifyPlain' causing a segfault, but I'll see about that on the github issue.